# IDEA and TypeScript imports

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

anybody knows how to change the default import formatting for the IDEA InteliJ from this:

```
import {Content} from "./Content";
```

to this

```
import { Content } from './Content';
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript, Spaces / Within / ES6 import/export braces.

Comment: This is ok for the spaces. Ty but what about the double quotes ? I want single quotes instead.

Comment: Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript, Punctuation / Use single quotes, always.